# Force Azure Services to go through Internet rather than backbone

Tags: azure, networking, routes, firewall

Is there a way to force traffic to Storage Account to go over Internet rather than Azure backbone? My scenario:

- Two Azure Tenants T1, T2
- T1 has Storage Account with Firewall enabled and restricted traffic to one of the T1's subnets
- T2 would like to access the SA in T1 through a public IP address exception in the SA's firewall
- We can't do Vnet peering between T1 and T2 for certain reasons

Is there a way to force traffic from T2 to T1's Storage Account to go over Internet rather than let Azure to route it over the Azure backbone?

Microsoft's doc says:

> If the destination address is for one of Azure's services, Azure routes the traffic directly to the service over Azure's backbone network, rather than routing the traffic to the Internet. Traffic between Azure services does not traverse the Internet, regardless of which Azure region the virtual network exists in, or which Azure region an instance of the Azure service is deployed in. You can override Azure's default system route for the 0.0.0.0/0 address prefix with a custom route."

In T2, as a test, I have deployed:

- Vnet
- AzureFirewallSubnet and Azure Firewall
- Subnet1

I've created a Route Table on Subnet1 with a Virtual Appliance Rule to go from 0.0.0.0/0 to the AF's private IP. It seems route the traffic to Storage Account through AF's firewall. However, it seems that as soon as a request from a VM in Subnet1 to the Storage Account reaches AF, it's routed through Azure backbone rather than AF's public IP.

Could you please advise, is there a way to force the traffic to go through the AF's public IP?

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to MSDN thread : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/04f8e6b9-c0ec-443d-b658-2126cdccc7e2/force-traffic-to-storage-account-to-go-over-internet-rather-than-azure-backbone?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork

Please check that for any updates.